# Allow multiple bearer token per user in ASP Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So far I have found other things, but not precisely this, I have a Web API setup and works with BearerToken only, and auth works fine, but the problem is that if the same user requests a second token (for example another device), invalidates the first token. How could I configure this feature on Web API? Besides using refresh tokens since for the time I can't implement that.

**EDIT**

Here I include the OAuth config section on Startup.Auth.cs, other programmer built this code, so I'm not sure how this work

```
    // Configure la aplicación para el flujo basado en OAuth
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Permitir que la aplicación use tokens portadores para autenticar usuarios
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Comment: It depends on how you set up your bearer tokens, can you show us some code?

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying.  Please clearly mention it with some code snippet, if you can.

Comment: Edited question to include some code

Comment: @ravindra I want to connect to my API with the same user but on different devices. On the login process I call www.api.com/Token with the credentials and request a Bearer token, but I have read that this invalidates other bearer tokens, what I want is that any previous token doesn't get invalidated